# Are Hindu scriptures pro- or anti-dowry?

Tags: scripture, practice, culture, marriage, women

Do Hindu scriptures discuss the topic of dowry (which Google defines as "property or money brought by a bride to her husband on their marriage")?

Do they take pro or anti stance on this practice?

**NOTE**:

This is not a duplicate of the other question (*[Origins of the dowry system](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/2146)*) which is about the origin of the dowry system i.e., how did this idea or practice develop over time, what was the original intention behind this idea, etc. This question however simply asks for direct references from scripture i.e., if there's a scriptural sanction for dowry.

Comment: Dowry has been mentioned and should be given. But a man using and living on dowry brought by his wife is highly condemned.

Comment: reference please?

Comment: Since this question may be closed, I am giving the reference here.A wife should never be purchased. Nor should a father sell his daughter. Only those persons of sinful soul who are possessed, besides, by cupidity, and who sell and purchase female slaves for making serving women, regard the status of wife as capable of arising from the gift and acceptance of a dowry.

Mahabharata AnusasanaParva Section XLIV

Comment: I don't know if "should be given" is mentioned, but I am sure that I read condemnation of men who use and live on dowry from wife's family, in Manu Smriti.

Answer (score 4):

**Condemnation of dowry**

> A wife should never be purchased. Nor should a father sell his
>   daughter. Only those persons of sinful soul who are possessed,
>   besides, by cupidity, and who sell and purchase female slaves for
>   making serving women, regard the status of wife as capable of arising
>   from the gift and **acceptance of a dowry**.

Mahabharata Anusasana Parva Section XLIV

During the times of Mahabharata till the beginning of the twentieth century bride price had to paid by the boy's family to the girl's family. Mahabharat as shown above explicitly condemns this practice. Nowadays the dowry is given by the girl's family to the boy's family. Mahabharata's condemnation of dowry would still stand since Mahabharata is condemning the idea that marriage is a business. One shouldn't profit from any marriage.