# How was Satyaki related to Krishna?

Tags: mahabharata

Satyaki and Krishna were Yadavas and Satyaki fought for Pandavas. All I know is that Satyaki is a student and friend of Arjuna and partial incarnation of Maruts.

**Satyaki was partial incarnation of Maruts , he was also committed to truthfulness .**

> सात्यकि: सत्यसन्धच्य योSसौ वृष्णिकुलोद्वह : |
>  पक्षात् स जज्ञ्ने
> मरुतां देवानामरिमर्दन: | | MB 1.67 ||
>
> P. 142 - And he who was Satyaki of sure aim, that upholder of the
> pride of Vrishni race, that oppressor of foes, **begotten of the portion
> of gods called the Maruts.**

[**Mahabharata -Book 1: Adi Parva - Sambhava Parva -SECTION LXVII** ][5]

---

My exact question is, how was Satyaki related to Krishna? Like was he his brother, cousin, how exactly was he related with Krishna? Please do not say that both of them are Yadavas. I know that but how exactly are they related?

Answer (score 0):

Kroṣṭā (son of Yadu) had two wives - Gāndhārī & Mādrī. Gāndhārī's son was Anamitra. And Mādrī had two sons- Yudhājit and Devamīḍhuṣa (Harivaṁśa [1.34.1-2](https://archive.org/details/Harivamsha-Purana-Gitapress/page/n161/mode/2up?view=theater)). Anamitra's son was Śini & Śini's son was Satyaka, who had Śaineya as upanāma. Satyaka's son was Sātyaki, who had upanāma Yuyudhāna. (Harivaṁśa [1.34.29-30](https://archive.org/details/Harivamsha-Purana-Gitapress/page/n163/mode/2up?view=theater)). Devamīḍhuṣa (who was the son of Kroṣṭā & Mādrī) had a son named Śūra. Among the many children of Śūra with Bhojarājakumārī, the eldest son was Vasudeva, who had upanāma Ānakadundubhi. (Harivaṁśa [1.34.17-18](https://archive.org/details/Harivamsha-Purana-Gitapress/page/n161/mode/2up?view=theater)). 
With his wife Devakī, Vasudeva borne Kṛṣṇa. (Harivaṁśa [1.35.7](https://archive.org/details/Harivamsha-Purana-Gitapress/page/n165/mode/2up?view=theater)).

Therefore, Sātyaki was a third cousin of Kṛṣṇa, and both of their closest common ancestor was their great-great grandfather Kroṣṭā, one of the many sons of Yadu. (Harivaṁśa [1.33.1](https://archive.org/details/Harivamsha-Purana-Gitapress/page/n155/mode/2up?view=theater)).

Above is the list from Harivaṁśa, which is pretty small compared to say list from Bhāgavata.
Below list from Yadu to Kṛṣṇa & Sātyaki would be detailed from Bhāgavata Purāṇa (9.23-24).

Yadu had 4 sons - Sahasrajit, Kroṣṭā, Nala, & Ripu. Since both Kṛṣṇa and Sātyaki are descended from Kroṣṭā, so only his lineage would be mentioned here, this would be followed later too. 
Kroṣṭā → Vṛjinavān → Śvāhi → Ruśeku, Citraratha → Śaśabindu → Pṛthuśravas → Dharma → Uśanas → Rucaka → Jyāmagha → Vidarbha → Kratha → Kunti → Dhṛṣṭi → Nivṛti → Darśāha → Vyoma → Jīmūta → Vikṛti → Bhīmaratha → Navaratha → Daśaratha → Śakuni → Karambhi → Devarāta → Devakṣatra → Madhu → Kuruvaśa → Anu → Puruhotra → Āyu → Sātvata → Vṛṣṇi I → Yudhājit → Anamitra (sibling of Śini I)

Anamitra had three sons, two of which are important to us viz. Śini II and Vṛṣṇi II.

Anamitra → Śini II → Satyaka → Yuyudhāna (Sātyaki) 
Anamitra → Vṛṣṇi II → Citraratha → Vidūratha → Śūra I → Bhajamāna → Śini III → Syayambhoja → Hṛdīka → Devamīḍha → Śūra II → Vasudeva → Kṛṣṇa

Based on this Yādava lineage mentioned in Bhāgavata Purāṇa (9.23-24), Sātyaki is grand-grand..... uncle of Kṛṣṇa, both of their closest common ancestor being Anamitra.

Comment: Isn't that illegal or frowned up as per Manu isn't it 9th generation only?

Comment: I don't understand, what you're trying to ask. Could you please make your question clearer? Is it related to this answer or a random question? Harivaṁśa is an authentic khilabhāga of Mahābhārata by Vyāsa, if you were asking about that. So, I haven't cited any unreliable śāstra, in this answer. @Haridasa

Comment: Sure, so I need look at the verse, but I believe Manu doesn't recommend marrying a girl 9 generations of her maternal or paternal side of the family, so isn't this breaking the law.

Comment: @Haridasa Well, this is not relevant to the OP's question or the answer. The question (posted by OP) is about the blood-relationship of Sātyaki & Kṛṣṇa. Sātyaki wasn't a female, he was the brother of Kṛṣṇa. Neither of them were women nor they had any intermarriage with one another. If you have another question, you have the option of posting it.

Comment: Man, once again I am.. I thought Satyaki was a girl name and jumped to conclusions sorry man.

Comment: @Haridasa It's alright. If you noted closely, I had mentioned 'Satyaka's son was Sātyaki'. His name is Sātyakiḥ technically (as also mentioned in the śloka quoted by OP), the visarga (ḥ) at the end of the name should leave no doubts regarding him having a male name.

Comment: Yes sir very nice, if you have time please fact-check this answer if you may I wish to make sure I read Bhishma's words regarding Arsha and Asura as correct or incorrect. https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/2146/origins-of-the-dowry-system/58555#58555

Comment: @Haridasa I don't think manu or any other dharmashastra mention 9 generation. The max is 7 generation that too line of ascent and descent taken together.

Comment: Looks like some names missing in this tree. Yadhu to Krishna is not just 3-4 generations, according to Adi Parva of Mahabharata. It guess as Yadhu...Kartavirya, Arjuna, Madhu...Vrishni...Krishna.

Comment: There are lots of lists in ithāsa-purāṇa (and they have a lot of differences), I just went with the one from Harivaṁśa. @Kanthri The answer is supported by citations, so if you find anything problematic, you can verify via those citations too.

Comment: @Kanthri I have added the list from Bhāgavata in the answer too.